# Java8 map Object property to another property in List Stream

Tags: dictionary, java-8, properties, java-stream

I need to map the 'count' property of the Source objects Stream to Target object's regCount & otherCount properties based on the indicator field by grouping them with PoNum property `[ Ex : if (indicator.equals("Y") ? regCount = 15: otherCount = 400)]`

Currently I'm doing something like the below

```
Map<Integer, List<SourceBean>> srcMap = srcBeanList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SourceBean::getPoNum, Collectors.toList()));
for (Entry<Integer, List<SourceBean>> entry : srcMap.entrySet()) {
    TargetBean tgtBean = new TargetBean();
    for(SourceBean srcBean : entry.getValue()) {
        tgtBean.setPoNum(srcBean.getPoNum());
        tgtBean.setVendor(srcBean.getVendor());
        if(srcBean.getIndicator().equals("N")) {
            tgtBean.setRegCount(srcBean.getLblCnt());
        }
        else if(srcBean.getIndicator().equals("Y")) {
            tgtBean.setOtherCount(srcBean.getLblCnt());
        }
    }           
   tgtBeanBeanList.add(tgtBean);
}
```

Please suggest how to achieve this mapping in Java 8 stream mapping possibly using flatmap

```
public class SourceBean {

    private Integer poNum;
    private String vendor;
    private String indicator (Y/N);
    private Integer count;
}
```

Source Json

```
[
    {
      "poNum" : 2490,
      "count" : 15,
      "vendor" : "Vend A",
      "indicator " : "Y"
    }, {
      "poNum" : 2490,
      "count" : 400,
      "vendor" : "Vend A",
      "indicator " : "N"
    }
]

public class TargetBean {

    private Integer poNum;
    private String vendor;
    private String regCount;
    private String otherCount;

}
```

Target Json

```
[
    {
      "poNum" : 2490,
      "regCount" : 15,
      "otherCount" : 400,
      "vendor" : "Vend A"}
]
```

Comment: Is `srcBeanList` the source json you provided? And what is `getLblCnt()`?

Answer (score 0):

I define a transform method named `List2Bean()`: it help to realize your forloop logic about combine SourceBeanList into one TargetBean. However it returns a List to apply for `stream` operation.

And then, focus on how I use `.values().stream().map()` operation. It is the key to realize your logic.

```java
public class Test {

    public TargetBean List2Bean(List<SourceBean> sourceBeanList){
        TargetBean tgtBean = new TargetBean();
        for(SourceBean srcBean : sourceBeanList) {
            tgtBean.setPoNum(srcBean.getPoNum());
            tgtBean.setVendor(srcBean.getVendor());
            if(srcBean.getIndicator().equals("N")) {
                tgtBean.setRegCount(String.valueOf(srcBean.getCount()));
            }
            else if(srcBean.getIndicator().equals("Y")) {
                tgtBean.setOtherCount(String.valueOf(srcBean.getCount()));
            }
        }
        return tgtBean;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Test test = new Test();

        List<SourceBean> srcBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
        srcBeanList.add(new SourceBean(2490, "Vend A", "Y", 15));
        srcBeanList.add(new SourceBean(2490, "Vend A", "N", 400));

        Map<Integer, List<SourceBean>> srcMap = srcBeanList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SourceBean::getPoNum, Collectors.toList()));

        //List<TargetBean> targetBeanList = (List<TargetBean>)
        List<TargetBean> tgtMaplist =
                srcMap.values().stream().map( e -> {return test.List2Bean(e.getValue());})
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

        tgtMaplist.stream().forEach(t -> {
            System.out.println(t.getPoNum() + " " + t.getVendor() + " " + t.getRegCount() + " " + t.getOtherCount() );
        });
    }
}
```